# Get the width of a div, button, etc. in CSS

Tags: html, css

```
button {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    (...)
}
button:before {
    width: (???);
    (...)
}
```

How can I get the button's width in `button:before` when the button's width is not fixed?

Comment: What you want to set the width to

Comment: In before you can't get the width of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
button {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    (...)
}
button:before {
    content:""; *// never forget to put content with empty strings. If you forget it will not work`*
   position:absolute; *//set this to position absolute and the parent which is the btn set position:relative*
   width:100%;
   height:100%; *// if you want the full size of the btn is like this*
   top:0;
   left:0
}

``
```

Answer (score 1):

> This helps you I think

```css
button{
position:relative;
}
button:before{
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;

}
```

```html
<button >Hi everyone! </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your button::before as big as button you can just to the following

```css
button {
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  position: relative;
}

button::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <button>Test</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Setting the `before` with `width: 100%` will give you just the same size as the button.